# Initialising an array while extracting __VA_ARGS__ from a macro function

Tags: arrays, c, embedded, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a special type handling for array data redundancy. The idea is to define and declare an array globally at compile time with fixed size, but the size is different to each declared array. This is the idea:

```
array[N] = { el1, el2, el3, ..., elN };
```

At first, I used the following syntax, which works:

```
#define ARRAY_DEFDEC(name, size, ...) \
    int arr_##name[size] = { __VA_ARGS__ }
```

When I use this macro I get the expected result:

```
// C code
ARRAY_DEFDEC(array_test, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
// Preprocessed
int arr_array_test[7] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
```

Now, for the problem I am having and don't know if it is possible to solve. While doing this, I also need to create a second array for which all the values will be inverted (using ~ operator or alternatively (0 - element + 1)). I have tried ~**VA_ARGS**, but naturally, it will only change the first element (in the above example with arr_array_test I will get -2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).

- Is it possible somehow to apply the `~` operator to all `__VA_ARGS__`?

I have a solution which would do the following:

```
#define ARRAY_DEFDEC(name, size, ...)
    int arr_##name[2*size] = { __VA_ARGS__ };
```

and then it would be used in the following way:

```
ARRAY_DEFDEC(test, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ~1, ~2, ~3, ~4, ~5, ~6, ~7)
```

This would require quite a lot of logic to be changed and a user needs to know that besides initialising elements, binary inverse needs to be provided, so I do not really prefer to do this.

At this moment in time I am assuming that argument size has the same size as size(`__VA_ARGS__`).

The arrays are intended to be used as a global definition (since they need to be accessed by multiple functions).

Note: Since it is an embedded system, external libraries cannot be included. There is not a single standard library on the system (e.g. stdio, stdarg, stdint, etc). This also further limits options. Standard which is used is C99 and compiler is from Green Hill Software.

Comment: There are ways to do it, but they're pretty hard.  The Boost Preprocessor library of headers would have the mechanism if you can decipher how to use it.  Or you can write it yourself (hard).  I'm not sure whether they'd make your code any more comprehensible — I have my doubts.

Comment: Is it truly unacceptable to initialize the second array at runtime?  That would have the additional benefit of decreasing the binary size.  (Or, look at where the array is used, and apply `~` on the fly.)

Comment: No it is not possible to do it on the fly due to time constraints for a low frequency CPU.

Comment: See Boost [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each.html) — the example appends `_` to each element of an argument list; you'd prepend `~` instead.

Comment: From comment below answer:  _" I am not working with C on a device such as a computer. "_.  Maybe add embedded tag here? and if it would help, say something about your environment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, isn't boost C++ only? Anyway I cannot include any external libraries.

Comment: @ryyker, I agree, good suggestion.

Comment: @Amaterastis — most of the Boost library is for C++ only because it makes extensive use of templates and other constructs only found in C++.  However, the Boost Preprocessor library is also usable in C.  It is a 'header only' library.  As near as possible, the C and C++ preprocessors work the same (except that the C++ one defines `__cplusplus` and the C one defines `__STDC__` and such like necessary differences).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible somehow to apply the ~ operator to all **VA_ARGS**?

No, you have to overload the macro on number of arguments.

Start with a generic FOREACH macro that allows to apply function f on each argument, here's an example for max up to 3 arguments:

```
#define FOREACH_1(f, x)  f(x)
#define FOREACH_2(f, x, ...)  f(x) FOREACH_1(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_3(f, x, ...)  f(x) FOREACH_2(f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_N(_3,_2,_1,N,...) FOREACH_##N
#define FOREACH(f, ...)  FOREACH_N(__VA_ARGS__,3,2,1)(f, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Then you would define the array and define a second one with inverted.

```
// note the comma
#define INVERT(x)  ~x,
#define ARRAY_DEFDEC(name, ...) \
    int arr_##name[] = { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    int secondarr_##name[] = { FOREACH(INVERT, __VA_ARGS__) };

ARRAY_DEFDEC(name, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I understand. This approach limits the max size of the elements which can be used and depends on number of macros which are overloaded, right? There is no way to somehow get around that?

Comment: Second question I have is about "note the comma". I am not sure I understand why it is there. It will preprocess FOREACH(~x, , __VA_ARGS__). Is one of the commas concated by __VA_ARGS__?

Comment: @Amaterastis: how big are the arrays you actually need?  Yes, the approach outlined here has a hard-coded upper bound.  You can extend that bound indefinitely, but it involves more and more macros.

Comment: The comma is needed because the splitting into tokens 'loses' the commas originally written.  Each element of `__VA_ARGS__` is a token without the comma.

Comment: `which are overloaded, right?` yes. `There is no way to somehow get around that?` No. Use something else then C to generate C code. Like Python.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like a solution to this would be one of those macros that consists of two dozen sub-macros, and those solutions always make me decide to solve the problem some other way.  Macros can do some things, but they're not a full programming language and so they're limited in what they can do.

I would just write a small utility to convert the raw data to C code and then #include that.  You can compile the utility as part of your compilation process and then use it to compile the rest of your code.  So your data.txt could just say "test 1 2 3 4 5 6 7" and your utility would output whatever declarations you need.

Comment: I need to stress that I am not working with C on a device such as a computer. There are no standard libraries such as stdio, stdint, stdargs, etc. nor is there a memory for .txt files. It is quite bare metal. :D
Welcome to stack and have fun :)

Comment: @Amaterastis This is something you would actually do on your build machine (which presumably is more capable), not the embedded device the final code runs on.

Comment: @Amaterastis What makes you think embedded systems aren't computers? You can't really use C without a computer. That would be some HDL language then.

Comment: I was outlining a common day idea of a computer (multi-thread, multi-core processor, high RAM/ROM, OS and all that is standardly available).

Answer (score 3):

A *much* better solution than variadic macros is to simply `#define` different initializer lists per array.

That is:

```
#define ARRAY_TEST_7 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }

int arr_array_test[] = ARRAY_TEST_7;
```

This is common practice. As opposed to inventing your private, project-specific macro language with `MAGIC_MACRO(my_variable, stuff);` which is very bad practice.

Optionally add something like:

```
static_assert(sizeof arr_array_test/sizeof *arr_array_test == expected_size,
              "error message");
```

And to solve inverted values:

```
#define ARRAY_TEST_7     {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7 }
#define ARRAY_TEST_7_INV { ~1, ~2, ~3, ~4, ~5, ~6, ~7 }
```

Please note that bitwise inversion of a plain `int` probably isn't the best idea for any purpose. (It does not give 2's complement but rather 1's complement) You should very likely use `uint32_t` and `u` suffix integer constants instead. Or in case you were actually looking for negative numbers, use `-` and not `~`.

---

Alternatively, and as a last resort, you can use "X-macros" to reduce code repetition. They are rather hard to read but at least some manner of industry standard, so that programmers used at reading them can tell what they do. As opposed to secret private macro language which *no* C programmer in the world knows nor wants to learn.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY3_VALUES(X)    \
/*  value */                \
  X(1)                      \
  X(2)                      \
  X(3)                      \

#define ARRAY7_VALUES(X)    \
/*  value */                \
  X(1)                      \
  X(2)                      \
  X(3)                      \
  X(4)                      \
  X(5)                      \
  X(6)                      \
  X(7)                      \


#define ARRAY_ITEM_INIT(val) (val),
#define ARRAY_ITEM_INIT_INV(val) (~(val)),

#define UINT32_ARRAY_DECLARE(size) \
  const uint32_t array##size[size] =  { ARRAY##size##_VALUES(ARRAY_ITEM_INIT) }

#define UINT32_ARRAY_DECLARE_INV(size) \
  const uint32_t array##size##_inv[size] =  { ARRAY##size##_VALUES(ARRAY_ITEM_INIT_INV) }



int main (void)
{
   UINT32_ARRAY_DECLARE(3);       // declares array3 with a given initializer list
   UINT32_ARRAY_DECLARE_INV(3);   // declares array3_inv with same initializer list but inverted
   UINT32_ARRAY_DECLARE(7);       // similar but some 7 item version
   UINT32_ARRAY_DECLARE_INV(7);

   for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
     printf("%"PRIx32 "%c", array3[i], i==2?'\n':',');

   for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
     printf("%"PRIx32 "%c", array3_inv[i], i==2?'\n':',');

   for(size_t i=0; i<7; i++)
     printf("%"PRIx32 "%c", array7[i], i==6?'\n':','); 

   for(size_t i=0; i<7; i++)
     printf("%"PRIx32 "%c", array7_inv[i], i==6?'\n':',');
}
```

Output:

```
1,2,3
fffffffe,fffffffd,fffffffc
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
fffffffe,fffffffd,fffffffc,fffffffb,fffffffa,fffffff9,fffffff8
```

Comment: The downside of this is that there's a risk of editing `ARRAY_TEST_7` and not editing `ARRAY_TEST_7_INV` — the two have to be kept in sync manually.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The best and simplest way to solve that is to place the inverted one directly below the non-inverted in source and align them with code formatting (see edit). Otherwise, something far more fishy like X macros is an option too, but it's a last resort.

Comment: I agree that 'int' is not the best approach. I am just trying to sketch the idea at the moment. I do not really like this approach, to be honest, because there is a plan to have multiple arrays of multiple different size with multiple different initialisers and I am trying to find a way to simplify usage on higher level, despite probably more complex code in the background.

Comment: I agree that code placement (and LOUD comments) may help, and the macro-based loopy solutions are fairly noxious (but they are automatic once set up).

Comment: @Amaterastis I can add an X macro version for completeness, it's icky, but not as icky as inventing a completely custom function-like macro language.

Comment: Done, I added an X macro example... which is pretty evil (and can be generalized to oblivion to reduce code repetition even more), but at least better than coming up with something completely custom.

Comment: (Also please note that this will generate multiple initializer lists placed in flash, so it will bloat flash memory compared to a version doing the inversion in run-time.)